# How to edit csv file?

Tags: java, android, csv, multiple-columns

Hello I am working on my custom barcode scanner and I have almost done everything just need help with .csv file customization. I need simple code that allow or place Scanned Code numbers in first column A only and to put the Date only in colmun B. (I have already script that writes these 2 vaulues correctly but in horizontall pozition without column separation)

Here is the code:

```
 try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/data.csv");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(scanContent);
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
                myOutWriter.append(datetime);
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "File created'mysdfile.txt'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. That's all you have to do -- put a comma between the columns.

Comment: I need to put it in here? myOutWriter.append(scanContent + ",");  or after this

Comment: Anywhere after `myOutWriter.append(scanContent)` but before `myOutWriter.append(datetime)`. You could write it on it's own like `myOutWriter.append(",")`, concatenate it to `scanContent` like `myOutWriter.append(scanContent + ",")`, or concatenate it to `datetime` like `myOutWriter.append("," + datetime)`.

Comment: Well I thought it's working but actually the first scanned code is placed correctly in A column but second code is linked with data  in column B

Comment: You need a new line between rows. Put `myOutWriter.append("\n")` after `myOutWriter.append(datetime)`.

Comment: @Djzewamars Accepted answers help other users find appropriate solutions quickly, and serve as a hat tip for the guy who helped solve your issue.